# Blonde girl in a pink dress with a chubby red guy, traveling in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for an anime in the 80s about a blonde girl who wore a pink dress and she was with a chubby red guy. There was a spaceship that they would travel on. The guy wore a crown. She seemed to control him. And she would cross her arms.

Answer (score 2):

A possible match is [*"Starzinger"* (*"Sci-Fi West Saga Starzinger"*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starzinger), also known as *"Spaceketeers"* and *"Sci-Bots"*, a series originally aired in 1978 in Japan and then dubbed and broadcast all over the world in the eighties.

The story transposes the *"Journey to the West"* Chinese novel (which was the source for other animes too, for example the early *"Dragonball"* and *"Saiyuki Reload"*) in a sci-fi setting.

The *blonde girl who wore a pink dress* would be **Princess Aurora**, leader of an expedition across the galaxy to reach the Great King planet and save the universe.

[image: Princess Aurora]

The *chubby red guy* is **Jan Kugo** (his name is sometimes different in the variuos translated versions), a member of the trio of cyborgs protecting and assisting Princess Aurora in her mission. Just as in your description, he wears a crown (or rather, a gold circlet) which, just like in the original Chinese legend, is used to control him and it activates when Aurora crosses her arms.

[image: Jan Kugo]